# Dependency property not updating the UI

Tags: c#, data-binding, dependency-properties

I am new to the binding concept and got stuck with the following.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Model model;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model();

        this.DataContext = model;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.Name = "My New Name";
    }
}

class Model : DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Model), new PropertyMetadata("My Name"));

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }       
}
```

I have bound the Name property to Text property of TextView. All I need to do is, on the button click I want to update the Name value that will have to update the text box value. I thought, if I use dependency property instead of normal CLR property, I dont need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

But the value in the UI is not updating as expected. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such control as TextView in WPF. What control is that?

Comment: this is Windows metro app not wpf.

Comment: Please show the binding expression.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that need to be addressed with your question. First of all, your model does not need to inherit from DependencyObject, rather it should implement INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

An object that implements INotifyProperty can then be used as a DependencyProperty in your page/window/object:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Model",
        typeof(Model), typeof(MainWindow));

    public Model Model
    {
        get { return (Model)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
    }
```

Finally, then, you can bind your TextBox.Text property to that in the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Click</Button>
    </StackPanel> 
</Grid>
```

The INotifyPropertyChanged is still necessary here because there needs to be a way for the UI to know that the model object has been updated.